# HTML purifier with WYSIWYG- looking for xss-clean alternative

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, security

So i have been using xss-clean package in node js. It was very powerful and simple,

```
const xss = require('xss-clean');
app.use(xss());
```

it was all it took to make it work. But since i started using Rich Editor, it is destructuring my html tags. So i was looking for an alternative to purify my html input.
There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-purify   html-purify package, but i have to manually use it on every input, but i would rather have it installed and working globally like xss-clean- just to simple lines of code, and it works. Do you know good alternative as simple as xss-clean?